# Read the date of a text file, change if pass two days and add a counter in the second line increment by 1

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to read a date saved in a text document in the format "Y/M/D", compare it with the current date, and if it is ok, do nothing, but if two days pass from the file date, add a line below with an incremental number (1, 2, 3, 4 ...). And update the date in the file with the present date.

This is what I have for now.
Example if today is 2020/06/02 the file is:

> 2020/06/02
>
> 1

And don't change if execute.

But if today is 2020/06/05 and execute the file should change like this:

> 2020/06/05
>
> 2

Etc.

I'm stuck, and this is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

# Generate file 1.txt
file = open("xxx\\1.txt", "w")

# Var
today = date.today()
counter = 1

# GEnerate present date
file.write(str(date.today()) + "\n")
file.close()
```

Comment: what is wrong with your code ? Is it not working or throwing any error?

Comment: Code works fine, print dates, but I cannot continue. I want a txt, with first line with the today date if is empty the file. THe second line I want the today date too. And the third line a increment number.
When I exec the file, read the date and compare with the real date, if the date is not correct, update the second line, and if pass two days later of first line(date), then the third lane increment by one. After 2 days update the first line.

Comment: can you explain this "read the date and compare with the real date, if the date is not correct, update the second line" what do you mean by not correct. It would be better if you explain with an example

Comment: For example today is 2020/06/02, the file contains: 2020/06/01 and second line 2020/06/02. Nothing should change. But if today is 2020/06/03 change first line to 2020/06/03 and second too. And because pass two days, the third line increment by 1, next to days, will be 2, etc.

Comment: why the example in post contain first line `2020/06/02` and 2nd line `2020/06/04` it should be `2020/06/03` as per your logic

Comment: Ok, I'll try be more simplistic. I want read the date of a file with this format "2020/06/02" and want compare with the present date. If is ok, don't touch, if not, change to the present date.

Comment: what about second and third line

Comment: Well, I think with 2 lanes is enought. So, if you have a date, and pass two days update to the new date and the second line increment a number by 1. If not pass two days don't modify the date. File: 2020/06/02 \n 1. And now if the date is 2020/06/05, exec the file and change the date in the file to 2020/06/05 \n 2. Sorry for the english.

Comment: I don't understand what you are telling. You changing your expected output in each comment you posted and one more thing example in your post should match what you are saying. you may get answers to your question if you edit your question with proper input and expected outptut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This below code will generate a new file with the present date and an integer. Now if you run this code after two days it will update as you asked.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

# Generate file 1.txt
if os.path.exists("xxx.txt"):
    file = open("xxx.txt",'r+')
else:
    file = open("xxx.txt","w+")
# replacing '-' to your default datetime in the txt file
today = str(date.today()).replace('-','/')
# reading the lines in the txt file
data = file.readlines()
# retriving only the date from the txt file dat
try:
# To check whether it is 2 days pass from the txt file date
    date_in_file = datetime.strptime(str(data[0].replace('\n','').replace('/','')),'%Y%m%d').date()
    print(date_in_file)
    if str(date_in_file+timedelta(2)).replace('-','/') == today:
        # To get the increment value from the txt file
        try:
            t=data[1]
        except:
            t=1
        #print(t)
            # deleting all the data from the file
        file.truncate(0)
        file.seek(0)
        # Updating the file with the present date 
        file.write(today+'\n')
        if t!=1:
            file.write(str(int(t)+1))
        else:
            file.write(str(t))
        file.close()
except:

    file.write(today+'\n')
    file.close()
```